# Pyinstaller exe: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_moduel'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I got a module not found error when I run package pdf_to_excel exe.

my_moduel is relative imports

I try --hidden-import but still not work.

and my_moduel and pdf_to_excel.py not in the same dir

```
 File "pdf_to_excel.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_moduel'

8: from  my_moduel import extract_title_content,ask_Ppt_info,create_quizlet_excel
```

Comment: Have you tried placing my_moduel.py in the same directory prior to using pyinstaller?

Comment: that works for me, but do you know how to do when they are not in the same file?